# How to set JDBC datasource targets to all servers in the cluster through WLST?

Tags: jdbc, weblogic, middleware, wlst

I have a WebLogic domain where in JDBC datasources are targeted to only one of the managed servers in the cluster. I need it to target to all servers in the cluster. I am able to target it to all servers through WebLogic console. But I need to perform the same through WLST. I tried `set()` to target to different managed servers. But what if there is a new managed server in future and i want the JDBC datasources to be pointed to the new one too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very simple you could try to use Jython jarray to pass the cluster name and also mention in the last argument that is target type as 'Cluster'.

```
clstrNam=raw_input('Cluster Name: ')
set('Targets',jarray.array([ObjectName('com.bea:Name='+clstrNam+',Type=Cluster')], ObjectName))
```

Please let me know if you still have challenges.
Reference link: [Generic datasource using WLST Example](http://wlstbyexamples.blogspot.in/2010/02/configuring-generic-datasource.html)
HTH